# How to get the Amazon Linux AMI version by AMI id?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance which runs an outdated Amazon Linux [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) (`ami-5256b825`).

To upgrade to the most recent [version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-ami-version-numbers.html), I first want to know what the differences between 2 images are. I only have the AMI ID (like `ami-6e7bd919`) and not the version number ([like `2014.09`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)).

I know that `ami-6e7bd919` corresponds to `2014.09.1` by looking at the AMI details when I follow the steps in the wizard to launch a new instance, but that's the most I could find out.

I have found the [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/#Release_Notes) for each version number, but I don't know how to match them with an AMI ID.

Does Amazon provide any official documentation in which I can match AMI ID's with their corresponding version numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [`describe-images`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) from the [EC2 service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html) in the [AWS command line tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/). You'll have to specify the AMI id for the `--image-id` argument.

From the docs:

> Describes one or more of the images (AMIs, AKIs, and ARIs) available
>   to you. Images available to you include public images, private images
>   that you own, and private images owned by other AWS accounts but for
>   which you have explicit launch permissions.
>
> **Note:**
>   Deregistered images are included in the returned results for an
>   unspecified interval after deregistration.

Execute the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
    --image-id ami-5256b825 \
    --query "Images[*].Description[]" \
    --output text \
    --region eu-west-1
```

This will be the result:

> amzn-ami-pv-2013.09.2.x86_64-ebs

Looking at the output, we can see that the version of the Amazon Linux AMI is `2013.09.2`. Looking for this on the [Amazon AMI portal](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/#Release_Notes), we'll be provided with this page containing the [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.09-release-notes/#2013.09.2_point_release_features) of this version.